# /etc/sysctl.conf abstraction for custom usage

Tags: configuration, libraries, sysctl

Is there an abstraction model for configuration files like /etc/sysctl.conf ?

I find it great for a few reasons, it's humanly readable, has nestable namespaces, hierachy of settings instead of one-dimension name value pairs.

I'd like to use a configuration file like that for my own needs. Is there a generic abstraction of the parser of that type of configuration file ?

PS: I've already considered ini files but it's one dimensional, I'm more interested in the hierarchical nature of sysctl configuration. I know macOS has a similar way to configure settings.